# connect to system in sqlplus using instant client mac

Tags: database, oracle, macos, sqlplus

I have downloaded sqlplus instant client on mac and have sqlplus working. I need to login as system and connect hr schema or make a new schema. i'm having problems connecting.

```
user@togo ~ % export PATH=~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8:$PATH
user@togo ~ % sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jul 1 11:43:25 2022
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sqlplus /nolog
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

If anyone could help me with this problem or guide me through the process of using sqlplus on Mac.

Comment: SQL\*Plus is a client; do you have an existing database to connect to - and if so have you set up your `tnsnames.ora` file so you have a TNS alias to use during login, or at least have the details for a easy-connect connection string?

Comment: i'm trying to connect to hr schema which already exists on oracle database. Can you  help me set up the tnsnames.ora?

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to figure out on what host your database is running and what the service names are that you can use to connect to.
2. Next create a tnsnames.ora using the info learned from 1 or use EZCONNECT to connect without tnsnames.ora

> ```
> assume your dbserver is reachable as linux01
> assume your database supports the service dbservice1
> assume the listener on linux01 for dbservice1 is on port 1521
> ```

your EZCONNECT can be done

using `sqlplus hr/bigsecretpassword@//linux01/dbservice01`

or if your listener is on a different port (1527) you can specify that

using `sqlplus hr/bigsecretpassword@//linux01:1527/dbservice01`

Lots of error message are possible. If you get errors, don't forget to specify the exact message you get. (and how long it took before it came)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Mac, but - generally speaking, database name (i.e. its *alias*) is specified along with username. Something like this on my MS Windows:

```
M:\>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Pet Srp 1 09:11:18 2022
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: scott@orcl                --> this!
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Active code page: 1250

SQL>
```